# Audio Mining and speech processing

Tags: audio, speech, mining

We are intending to do a project on audio mining.It basically takes input from the user and processes the data input and gives desired results(but only on numbers).We are trying to design an android application for the same.If user inputs say "12345" then it should look for the data stored in db and do some processing and provide us details.Can anyone give insight into what can be done or where to start from.

Comment: This question is very vague. You should try on your own and come back if you run into troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can't understand what you are trying to do.....what do you intend for "desired results"??....anyway it seems that you need to learn something about "feature extraction" and "information retrieval" arguments. in other hands you must

1. process your data in order to find relevant information that describes univocaly your multimedia contents (see "feature extraction")

2.set a distance metric to search over your DB the item which is more "similar" (behind this word there are so many concepts to explain....see "information retrieval") to user-submitted content

3.implement a speed search over your data

this is a simple resume of a complex branch of computer science.....if you already know these things and/or need something more specific, make your question more specific!